# Is there overhead in accessing an array stored in a member object, as opposed to accessing the array directly?

Tags: c++, arrays, object, pointers

I have many meshes each with many triangles, and an algorithm that needs to loop over *all* the triangles, while also maintaining knowledge of which mesh each triangle comes from.  T here are several ways I could imagine doing this.

Option 1 is to first pack all of the vertices (represented as a `Vector3<double>`) in a single array, and having a separate array store which mesh it came from:

```
void my_function(){
    ...
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_vertices; i++){
        Vector3<double>& current_vertex = vertices[i];
        size_t mesh_id = mesh_ids[i];
        ...
    }
};
```

Option 2 is to have each model maintain the array of vertices it owns, and then simply loop over each mesh:

```
void my_function(){
    ...
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_meshes; i++){
        for (size_t j = 0; j < meshes[i].num_vertices; j++){
            Vector3<double>& current_vertex = meshes[i].vertices[j];
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Option 3 (which is what matches best with my current implementation architecture) is to have each a pointer to each mesh belong to a `Model` object (`Model` contains other information about the model that I need, but isn't strictly mesh information), and then loop over each model like this:

```
void my_function(){
    ...
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_models; i++){
        for (size_t j = 0; j < models[i].mesh->num_vertices; j++){
            Vector3<double>& current_vertex = models[i].mesh->vertices[j];
            ...
        }
    }
```

My question is:  Is there a performance benefit to any one of these approaches?  Option 1 is the biggest departure from my current architecture but is there any performance benefit to directly accessing an array without needing to go through an intermediate object?  And similarly, is there any performance penalty to having two intermediate objects as with Option 3 (with an instance of `Model` contains a pointer to an instance of `Mesh` which contains the array)?

Comment: Forget about possible overhead and just follow what's best from your architecture POV. Compiler might optimize it out when possible, like in this [trivial example](https://godbolt.org/z/PTWdx9M18), but the best way to know if there is a bottleneck is to simply benchmark your code.

Comment: pondering about what would be faster, never made something actually faster. The only way is to implement it and measure.

Comment: `Vector3<double> current_vertex = models[i].mesh->vertices[j];` -- If the goal is to work with the actual vector in `models[i].mesh`, then you should be using a reference to the vector, and not make a copy.  `Vector3<double>& current_vertex = models[i].mesh->vertices[j];`.  Then the whole question of what has more overhead becomes moot.

Comment: If the compiler can compute the appropriate offsets in every array element, there is no penalty. But if the access is indirect via a pointer, the access time is longer, especially if the elements are scrambled.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes I apologize, I was trying to write some shorthand to demonstrate accessing the vertices.  In reality, what I currently have is just operating directly on `models[i].mesh->vertices[j]`, such as having `models[i].mesh->vertices[j][ind]`, though creating a reference so I could just deal with `vertex[ind]` would be more readable.  I modified the post to better reflect that.

With that being the case, you're saying these are the same in terms of speed?  Needing to go through the pointer at `models[i].mesh` is no more expensive than just directly accessing an array?

Comment: With a reference, you are accessing the actual vector.  If your goal is to do this, using a reference is more than likely faster than repeatedly having `models[i].mesh->vertices[j]` being stated in a loop.  For example: `for(...) { models[i].mesh->vertices[j].push_back(...); models[i].mesh->vertices[j].erase(...);...` goes through multiple indirections by using `[]`, while `auto& vref = models[i].mesh->vertices[j]; for(...) { vref.push_back(); vref.erase();...` has no such issue.

Comment: Ok thanks!  Also just to be clear, vertices is of type `Eigen::Matrix<double,3,1>`, not `std::vector`.  But I believe your points still stand regardless?

Comment: Yes, the point still stands, even if the type is not vector.  There are tools (I use a commercial one) that can identify spots in code like this, where creating a reference and using the reference instead of repeated calls to `[]` with the same index being used is preferred.  In addition, `[]` may be a function call if it is overloaded -- additional overhead that is solved by using a reference.

Comment: Beginners always seem to start worrying about performance prematurely - and focusing attention on concerns that they think are a big deal but really don't matter much.  Start by thinking about an algorithm to *correctly* produce required results, and implementing it correctly.  Once that is achieved, measure/benchmark performance of your code and, only if *measured* performance is insufficient, use the measurements to identify hot-spots (sections of code that drive performance, so optimising them will be most beneficial).